If $X$ is a set of initial ordinals then is $\sup X$ initial one?
An ordinal $\kappa$ is said initial whether it is not equipotent to any (strictly) minor ordinal: so we know that the supremum of a set of ordinal is an ordinal and thus I tried to prove or disprove if the supremum of initial ordinals is an ordinal one but I only elaborated what to follow whitout successfull.

MY ATTEMPT
If $\sup X$ is not initial then there exists $\alpha<\sup X$ such that the equality
$$
|\sup X|=|\alpha|
$$
so that let be $f$ a bijection from $\sup X$ to $\alpha$. Now $\sup X$ is the less ordinal biegger than any $x\in X$ so that  be $\lambda$ the smallest $\lambda$ such that the inequality
$$
\alpha<\lambda
$$
holds. So I tried to prove that $f\restriction_\lambda$ is a bijection (this is trivial) from $\lambda$ to (this is not trivial) any ordinal less the $\alpha$ but I failed.

So I ask to prove or disprove the statement- with a counterexample: could someone help me, pelase?

Okay, now if $\sup X$ was equipotent to $\alpha$ then $|\sup X|$ and $\alpha$ would be equal but by the last inequality this is false and so by reductio ad absurdum the statement follows, right?

Unfortunately it seems we post contemporary the (our) last comment: see my last, sorry.

Perfect: thanks for the clarification. Obviously if you will post an answer I will accept it. :-)

@SassatelliGiulio - Sorry, I was writing the answer while you were commenting. I didn't see it. I can delete my answer.

@GiulioSassatelli Since the question is solved I will accept the Taroccoesbrocco's answer: however if you will wrote an answer I will accept it!

Yes, the supremum $\sup X$ of a set $X$ of initial ordinals is indeed an initial ordinal.
I guess you already know that $\sup X$ is an ordinal. So, let us prove that it is initial.
Let $\beta < \sup X$. By definition of $\sup$ (that is, of union), there is some $\gamma \in X$ such that $\beta < \gamma \subseteq \sup X$, hence there is an injection from $\beta$ to $\gamma$.
If $|\sup X| = |\beta|$, then there would be an injection from $\gamma$ to $\beta$, as the result of the restriction to $\gamma$ of the bijection from $\sup X$ and $\beta$, thus $|\gamma| = |\beta|$, which contradicts the fact that $\gamma \in X$ is initial. Therefore, $|\beta| < |\sup X|$ and thus $\sup X $ is initial.

Hi, can I ask your help here, please? Initially I thought I found a solution but I catch a crab'. Forgive the bother.
